# RxJS take value from observable that emitted

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two observables, `searchText` and `offset`.  Search text emits a value when a user enters some some criteria in a text box, while offset emits when a user is scrolling the results in an infinite scroll.

What I am trying to do here is to set my `infiniteSiteList` to the result of the  observable that actually emitted the value.  For example, if the user is simply scrolling, and there are more results in the infinite scroll, `infiniteSiteList` should be set to the output of `batchMap`, however, if the user is typing some text to search, then `infiniteSiteList` should be set to the output of `searchMap`.  I was thinking `race` is the right operator, however, it seems like it only takes the first value of batchMap, so it breaks the scrolling behavior.  What is the RxJS operator I can use to perform this?

```
const searchMap = this.searchText.pipe(
    throttleTime(500),
    mergeMap(searchText => this.getBatch(null, searchText))
);

const batchMap = this.offset.pipe(
    throttleTime(500),
    mergeMap(n => this.getBatch(n, this.searchText.getValue())),
    scan((acc, batch) => {
        return [...acc, ...batch];
    }, new Array<SiteListItem>())
);

this.infiniteSiteList = race([searchMap, batchMap]).pipe(
    tap(data => console.log(data))
);
```

Comment: You need to switch off of the initial search and then into the paging. This way each new search resets the paging

Comment: The race operator is meant for a different purpose. For your use case, you can ditch the pipe for subscribing to observable. Instead, just subscribe. in the handler function of subscribe you can set infiniteSiteList to the result. You can still use the throttling with subscribe.

Comment: I can post a snippet for your use case if you want to go with the approach I am suggesting.

Comment: With @blid answer you can get away with less code change using merge(). Try that first.

Answer (score 0):

`race` will check whichever observable emits first and then only take values from that observable.

It all depends on how you want to swap between the sources of `infiniteSiteList`. If you want to be able to swap indefinitely:

```
this.infiniteSiteList = merge(batchMap, searchMap);
```

If you want to swap from one to another, but not back again, then just add a `takeUntil`.

```
const batchMap = this.offset.pipe(
   ...,
   takeUntil(searchMap)
);

this.infiniteSiteList = merge(batchMap, searchMap);
```

Comment: with merge is it possible to find out emited value came from which observable (batchMap or searchMap) ? As both are handled in different way.